# Select exactly 5 rows from a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an odd requirement which ideally should be solved in SQL, not the surrounding app.

I need to select exactly 5 rows regardless of how many are actually available.  In practice the number of rows available will usually be less than 5 and on some rare occasions it will be more than 5.  The "extra" rows should have `null` in every column.

*The app is written in a technology that isn't Turing Complete.  This requirement is much more difficult to solve in the app's code than you might imagine!  To describe it, the app is effectively a transformer: It takes in a bunch of queries and spits out a report.  So please understand the app is NOT written in a "programming language" in the traditional sense.*

So for example, if I have a table:

```
A | B
-----
1 | X
2 | Y
3 | Z
```

Then a valid result would be

```
A    | B
-----------
2    | Y
1    | X
3    | Z
null | null
null | null
```

I know this is an unusual requirement. Sadly it can't be solved in the application due to the technology being used.

Ideally this shouldn't require changes to the database but if there is no other way that changes can be arranged.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Perhaps test this on a server, and when you have the code working post an answer.  Right now what you are suggesting doesn't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
select top 5 a, b
from (select a, b, 1 as priority from t union all
      select null, null, 2 cross join
             (values(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)) v(5)
     ) x
order by priority;
```

That is, create dummy rows, append them, and then choose the first five.

I do think that this work should be done in the app, but you can do it in SQL.

Comment: Thanks. I agree it should be in the app.  Sadly the technology calling SQL is a pig to work with.

Answer (score 3):

```
Create Table #Test (A int, B int)
Insert #Test Values (1,1)
Insert #Test Values (2,1)
Insert #Test Values (3,1)

Select Top 5 * From
    (
    Select A, B From #Test
    Union All
    Select Null, Null
    Union All
    Select Null, Null
    Union All
    Select Null, Null
    Union All
    Select Null, Null
    Union All
    Select Null, Null
    ) A
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap this in a stored proc..

```
declare @rowcount int 
select top 5* from dbo.test
set @rowcount=@@rowcount

if @rowcount<5
Begin
select * from dbo.test  
union all
select null  from dbo.numbers where n<=5-@rowcount
End
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use some sort of tally table (although the numbers themselves do not matter, only that the table has enough records), you can use it to create the dummy rows. e.g. using sys.columns:

```
select top 5 a,b from
(
    select a, b, 0 ord from yourTable
    union all 
    select null a,null b, 1 from sys.columns
) t
order by ord
```

The advantage of the tally would be that if you need another number of rows in the future, you only need to change the top x (provided the tally table has enough rows)

Answer (score 0):

Get those 3 records from your table.
Take a counter variable.
and then from your code add the NULL content until your counter gets 5.

Comment: That's not a language it is pure database. Such scenario wouldn't work for it.

Comment: It is possible if you use a cursor but I wouldn't recommend that approach.